# How to import confiurable product?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, import, product-import

I have search over every place but didn't got any valuable response.

Can anyone have idea how exactly magento handle import process.Even i have Download Sample File from magento import section.

Surprisingly,the provided Csv doesn't have any configurable product.

I never understand how magento hande configurable product.

Can any please guide here or any sample CSV.

Please provide tested csv i have used mandy from web but none of its working correctly.

Comment: Here is a complete guide with in-depth decription and sample files https://firebearstudio.com/blog/the-complete-guide-to-magento-2-configurable-products.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is working csv to import configurable products
First of all you need to create an configurable attribute at backend

- Go to store attributes->proudct and select color than under properties add color option "Black" and save
- Go to system under data transfer->import ,import setting > products > import behavior add/update > file to import (select attached file)> check data > import
- CSV file link http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=17016345802752495677
- Two virtual products each associted with configurable product screenshot attached

[image]

Comment: it has just config product where is simple product?

Comment: Instead of simple product in CSV there are two virtual products , you can make them simple products by adding weight.